# How do I make characters appear using getch()?

Tags: c, xcode, windows, input, getch

When I'm using `getch()` function and run my code, I don't see the characters that I'm inputting.

It is like they are hidden from what reason.

Does anyone know how can I make them appear while inputting them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getche()` or better `_getche()` instead of `getch()` to **echo** the input.

`getch()` and `_getch()` only fetch characters without displaying them to the console.

The *e* in `getche()` stands for **echo**.

From the Microsoft docs:

> The `_getche` and `_getwche` functions read a single character from the console with echo, meaning that the character is displayed at the console.
>
> Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getche-getwche?view=vs-2019

Furthermore, the use of `getche()` and `getch()` is deprecated by Microsoft. Use the versions with the preceding underscore instead:

> The Microsoft-specific function name `getche` is a deprecated alias for the `_getche` function. By default, it generates Compiler warning (level 3) C4996. The name is deprecated because it doesn't follow the Standard C rules for implementation-specific names. However, the function is still supported.
>
> Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getche?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

you should use function getche() ,it will display the character also.